# Pygame run on external screen using ssh

Tags: ssh, putty, terminal, pygame, lcd

I have a raspberry pi with a lcd screen attached witch is mirroring the raspberry pi's display. I want to show a pygame window on it. When I run: `python main1.py` on the ripi terminal the pygame window pops up perfectly on the ripi display.

However I am running my raspberry pi remotely from my windows machine using putty ssh. When I run `python main1.py` on there it comes up it return `pygame.error: Unable to open a console terminal`. From what I have read online it is trying to show the pygame display on my ssh putty window. I do not want this I want to have it show on my raspberry pi screen.

Is there a setting in putty or something in my script i can change to do this?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24351/remotely-control-an-xorg-session).
I tested the solution between two of my personal computers, both running Linux.

To find out the value of $DISPLAY, use a keyboard hooked directly to the pi. Then in the terminal type `echo $DISPLAY`
The value will probably be :0.0

Then once you ssh into the pi, type
`export DISPLAY=:0.0`
(but replace the :0.0 with whatever value the `echo $DISPLAY` turned up).
Also, if you don't have a keyboard, it's probably worth just assuming your display variable is :0.0 above.

Also make sure you have X forwarding enabled in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config